# How to publish to Instagram with RestFB in Java?

Tags: java, instagram, publish, restfb

I'm trying to do a simple app that can publish photos to my business Instagram page. I've been looking around on the internet and I couldn't find a way to publish on it. The Business Account in question is associated with a facebook page, and I'm using the page's access token to create the DefaultFacebookClient. I've successfully published a picture to the page using the code below, but now I need to publish it to Instagram.

```
FacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient("facebook_page_access_token", Version.LATEST);

URL url = new URL("img_url");
InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

FacebookType photo = client.publish("facebook_page_id/photos" , FacebookType.class,
    BinaryAttachment.with("name", stream.readAllBytes()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the Content Publishing API is in closed beta so I won't be able to post photos to Instagram any time soon.